# In EWL, how do I clear scroll position when navigating to the same page with different query parameters?

Tags: c#, navigation, scroll, enterprise-web-library

I am on MyPage.aspx?questionNumber=1 and I am navigating to MyPage.aspx?questionNumber=2. I am using this code create the navigation between the two:

```
EwfUiStatics.SetContentFootActions( new ActionButtonSetup( "Next",
                                                                           EwfLink.Create(
                                                                               new Info( es.info, new OptionalParameterPackage { QuestionNumber = info.QuestionNumber + 1 } ),
                                                                               new ButtonActionControlStyle() ) ) );
```

Notice I am using "new Info" and re-using the entity's info object. Maybe I should be using GetInfo or something else, instead.

When I get to the next question, I am scrolled halfway down the page. I want to be at the top. How do I force the scroll position to be cleared (or more generally, how do I specify the info object so that I don't have undesired carry-over from the previous page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you navigate (including whether you reuse `Info` objects or not) makes no difference in what is retained. Even something like this (in a `DataModification`) would produce the same results you're seeing:

```
parametersModification.QuestionNumber += 1;
```

Currently EWL does not have strong support for picking and choosing the state you want to retain after an intra-page navigation. But for scroll position in particular, you may be able to override `EwfPage.scrollPositionForThisResponse` to get what you want. You could unconditionally return `ScrollPosition.TopLeft` as long as the page never does post backs in which you *want* to retain scroll position.

Comment: I'm ok with not being able to pick and choose state I want to retain. Is there a way to say that I don't want any state retained at all?

Comment: No; EWL doesn't support that right now either. But it could definitely be implemented. Also, if your page was *not* acting as an auto data modifier, your `EwfLink` would render just as a link and clicking it would not retain anything.